# Get request parameter not triggering if statement in Django

Tags: django, get

Django newbie.

I'm trying to pass 'id_numb' as a get request, here's the URL: mysite/?id_numb=1. However, it does not make it to the second if statement.

```
if request.GET['id_numb']:
        id_numb = request.GET['id_numb']
        if id_numb == 1:
            # doesn't make it here - never get to this code, even when 1 is passed
            ....different code
        else:
            ....some code
    else:
        .... some other code
```

Comment: `request.GET['id_numb']` might be a ***string***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can try

```html
if request.GET['id_numb']:
        id_numb2 = request.GET['id_numb']
        id_numb = int(id_numb2)
        if id_numb == 1:
            # doesn't make it here - never get to this code, even when 1 is passed
            ....different code
        else:
            ....some code
    else:
        .... some other code
```